# Zero to One (Optional One to One) Entity Relationship Issue (attempted to assign null one-to-one property)

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Unable to update entity for optional one to one relationship using spring data jpa(2.1.2.RELEASE) and spring boot(2.1.2.RELEASE)

Getting the error attempted to assign null one-to-one property

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "table_a")
public class EntityA {

 @Id
String id;

String aa;
int bbb;

@Nullable
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "inv",  optional = true,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
EntityB bEntity;
```

}

```
@Entity
public class EntityB{

@Id
String id; 

String aaa;

String nnnn;

@OneToOne
@MapsId
@JoinColumn(name = "id")
EntityA  aEntity;
```

}

DAO Code as below
    Optional eA = entARepo.findById("1234");

```
    EntityA entA= null;

    if (eA.isPresent()) {
        entA= eA.get();
    }

    EntityB eB = entA.getBEntity();
    if (Objects.isNull(eB)) {
        eB= new EntityB();

        eB.setAAA("12121");

        eB.setAEntity(entA);

        entA.setBEntity(entB);
    }
    repository.save(entA);
```

}``

Comment: can u update the error log

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by using a join table instead of a shared primary key approach. would still to know how to make the shared primary key approach work for optional one to one relationship